# JPA Criteria: issue of querying properties of subclass

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, which supports JPA 2.1. I need to build  a complex query based on user input. 
I got the rest done and working, but I still have this problem. Let's put metamodel or other solutions aside to see how the current problem can be solved.

The following are  the class structure and their relationships:

```
class BaseObject implements Serializable {
}

class A extends BaseObject{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aref", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true) 
    private List<B> blist;

}

class B extends BaseObject {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aref")
    private A aref; 

}

//-------------NOTE THAT IS A SUBCLASS OF B------------
class C extends B {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cref", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true) 
    private List<D> dlist;

}

class D {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cref")
    private C cref; 

    String name;
}
```

Now I want to get a list A objects whose, after join, the value of the "name" field in class D is "John". Here is what I have:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

Root<A> root = cq.from(A.class); 
CriteriaQuery<Object> select = cq.select(root);

Join bjoin = root.join("blist");     
Join cjoin = cb.treat(bjoin, C.class); 
Join djoin = cjoin.join("dlist");      //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
Predicate p = cb.equal(djoin.get("name"), "John");

cq.where(p);

Query query = em.createQuery(select);
List<A> result = query.getResultList();
```

but I keep getting the following error:

Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [dlist] on this ManagedType [BaseObject]

Is what I am doing correct? How to fix this problem? I thought using the treat method should help to find the property on the subclass.

Thanks!